# solving google captcha with 2captcha in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, recaptcha, captcha

i saw a video on YouTube that can solve captcha with puppeteer and 2captch it work I received the solution and it placed in

`g-recaptcha-response`

but the problem there is no button to procced to the next page the captcha appear at its own page like the following pic:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GS21.png)

I tried to reload the page using this line of code

`await page[0].reload({ waitUntil: ["networkidle0", "domcontentloaded"] });`

I print out the page title to be able to see if the captcha page solved:

`var pagetitle3 = await page[0].title();`

`console.log(pagetitle3);`

It work only in headless mode is false but when the headless mode is true it won't

YouTube link: https://youtu.be/wsDRkAD6lPs
source code: https://jsoverson.medium.com/bypassing-captchas-with-headless-chrome-93f294518337

if anyone can help me
tank you very much :-)

Comment: There is an amazing API that's doing it like puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha

Comment: the problem the page don't have any button to submit or something the reload the page the captcha appear on it's own page